# Как в корзине woocommerce можно вывести текст после цены товаров определённой категории не затрагивая итоговую цену?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется 2 категории товаров: `beer` & `snack`.

Как в корзине можно вывести текст после цены товаров определённой категории, не затрагивая итоговую цену?

Допустим, после цены за `пиво` указать что это цена за `литр`. А в цене за `закуску` указать что это за `50 грамм`.

Фото прилагается чтобы был более понятнее мой вопрос.

И ещё маленький вопросик:

Kак можно вывести *единицу измерения в инпуте* в корзине дописать к количеству категории `пиво` (л.) и к количеству категории `закуски` (гр.)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи можно использовать плагин [Measurement Price Calculator](https://woocommerce.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/).

Так товар выглядит в админке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так - в корзине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]